# How to interpret this paragraph?

Tags: translation, interpretation

Below, you can see the middle part of page 25 of [Common Methodology for Information Technology Security Evaluation](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/files/ccfiles/CEMV3.1R4.pdf) document:

> The CEM recognises three mutually exclusive verdict states:
>   **a) 
>   Conditions for a pass-verdict are defined as an evaluator completion 
>   of  the  CC  evaluator  action  element  and  determination  that  the
>   requirements for the PP, ST or TOE under evaluation are met. The 
>   conditions for passing the element are defined as:**
>
> 1)  the constituent work units of the related CEM action, and;
>
> 2)  all evaluation  evidence  required  for  performing  these  work  units 
>   is  coherent,  that  is  it  can  be  fully  and  completely 
>   understood by the evaluator, and
>
> 3)  all  evaluation  evidence required  for  performing  these  work  units  does  not  have  any 
>   obvious  internal  inconsistencies  or  inconsistencies  with  other 
>   evaluation  evidence.  Note  that  obvious  means  here  that  the 
>   evaluator  discovers  this  inconsistency while performing the work
>   units: the evaluator  should  not  undertake  a  full  consistency 
>   analysis  across  the  entire  evaluation  evidence  every  time  a 
>   work  unit  is  performed.

My problem is understanding the paragraph that is in bold.

Actually I wonder which one of the following interpretations is correct:

**First interpretation:**

Conditions for a pass-verdict **are**:

1. An evaluator must complete *CC evaluator action element*. and
2. It must be determined that requirements are met.

**Second interpretation:**

Conditions for a pass-verdict **will be defined just after that**:

1. An evaluator  completed *CC evaluator action element*. and
2. It is determined that requirements are met.

---

As you see above , in the first interpretation, I considered "**as**" equal to "**as following**"; and in the second interpretation, I considered it equal to "**just after**". Which one is correct?

If the first interpretation is correct, then what are the conditions 1, 2 and 3 in the end of quoted text?

Comment: Figure 3 in your document should be helpful. It shows three elements, each with a different verdict: pass, inconclusive, and fail. Your excerpt a) is only about one of the three, the *pass* verdict.

Comment: Well, How it can help me to understand which one of interprets are correct?!

Answer (score 2):

> Conditions for a pass-verdict are defined as an evaluator completion of the CC evaluator action element and determination that the requirements for the PP, ST or TOE under evaluation are met.

Bleh, terrible sentence.  Here's the simplified "core" of the sentence:

> Conditions ... are defined as a[n] ... completion ... and determination.

So, for a "pass-verdict" to occurr, there must be a successful completion (of some kind) and a successful determination (of some kind).

This text tells you about the kind of completion:

> ... evaluator completion of the CC evaluator action element

This text tells you about the kind of determination:

> ... that the requirements for the PP, ST or TOE under evaluation are met.